# Select sum from 1-15 and 16-31 on a month

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
(SELECT
SUM(total)
FROM `earnings`
WHERE user_id = $userid
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%m')) = '11'
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%Y')) = '2020'
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%d')) <= '15')
as first,
(SELECT
SUM(total)
FROM `eearnings`
WHERE user_id = $userid
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%m')) = '11'
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%Y')) = '2020'
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%d')) >= '16')
as second
FROM `earnings`
```

What I want to do is that every userid to have in every month access to the sum of earnings from 1-15 and 16-30..

In my result..with this query I get over 100 records with the same values..for ex :

```
 first : 150 second: 300
```

If I use Limit 1 ..the query shows only one record with the correct values ..
My question is if my query is good or i missmatch something, because if I run every query separeted it returns only one row without limit 1.
Thank you for the help !

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%m')) = '11' AND .. AND ..` no, no, and really no. This is not how you ask a database to return you all dates between the 1st and 15th of nov. `WHERE date_earn >= '2020-11-01' AND date_earn < '2020-11-16'` will be fine, performs no per-row data conversions, maintains a chance of using an index and critically doesn't compare numbers using strings (hint: `DATE_FORMAT(date_earn, ('%d')) <= '15'` is false for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th... can you work out why?)

Comment: thank you for your reply..i will use your version ..but on query i get same 348 result..with the exact same values...why ?

Comment: I don't get the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `SELECT ... FROM earnings`. This gives you one result row per row in the earnings table. For each of these rows you select the two sums. Again and again the same two sums. If you just remove the final `FROM earnings`, this will tell the DBMS that you just want one row.

As has been mentioned there are other ways to write this query. This is how I'd do this:

```
SELECT
  SUM( CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(date_earn) <= 15 THEN total END ) as first,
  SUM( CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(date_earn) >= 16 THEN total END ) as second
FROM earnings
WHERE user_id = $userid
AND date_earn >= DATE '2020-11-01'
AND date_earn <  DATE '2020-12-01';
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Thank you , with my query i was getting more than 370 results with the same values..with your query I get only one result ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but I think you can make use of conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   SUM( (@var_day_of_month := DAYOFMONTH(date_earn)) BETWEEN 1 AND 15) * total ) First,
   SUM( (@var_day_of_month BETWEEN 16 AND 31) * total ) Second
FROM earnings
WHERE TRUE
# AND user_id = 3
# AND YEAR(date_earn) = 2020
# AND MONTH(date_earn) = 11
GROUP BY user_id
;
```

Comment: why do you have a `+0`?

Comment: There are better ways to pull the day out of a date in MySQL than formatting the date to a string and getting an implicit conversion by adding 0. WHERE TRUE is unnecessary (delete the clause), and you alias the table then never use the alias. This query can(should) be rewritten using standard SQL (CASE WHEN) so it could be easily applied to another DB in future (for the OP or for future visitors)

Comment: (Added another couple of recommendations)

Comment: @CaiusJard Not sure how to do it with case, or how what I currently have does not work for standard sql. [`WHERE TRUE`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/409719/250313) exists for the mere reason of making other conditions toggled.